# how to bind javascript function with OnClientClick event with Eval?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eval, onclientclick

my link button -

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnEdit" Text="edit" OnClientClick="javascript:msgDisp('<%# Eval(LocationId).toString() %>')" />
```

and the javascript msgDisp is-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function msgDisp(lid) {            
        alert(lid);
    }
</script>
```

**but it is not giiving LocationId in pop but the whole string <%#......%> is comin in popup message.** How can I pass Eval values in javascript.

Comment: Is the link button in a databound control? If not, you need to call `lbtnEdit.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 13):

You can build the entire contents of `OnClientClick` as a string within the code brackets and it will output like you're expecting.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnEdit" Text="edit" 
    OnClientClick='<%# "msgDisp(" + Eval("LocationId") + ");" %>' />
```

This is assuming LocationId is a valid number- there are no quote marks to wrap your value when it renders, so outputting something like `msgDisp(hello);` is going to break. I don't know how to address that in this manner, so if you have to do that I would recommend setting `OnClientClick` server side during the `ItemDataBound` event. Here's what it would like where the parent is a `Repeater` control.

```
protected void notesRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass item = (MyClass)e.Item.DataItem;
    LinkButton lbtnEdit = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnEdit");
    lbtnEdit.OnClientClick = string.Format("msgDisp('{0}');", item.LocationId);
}
```

Comment: if you want quotes around it like in `msgDisp('hello');` then you can use the HTML entity like: `OnClientClick='<%# "msgDisp(&#39;" + Eval("LocationId") + "&#39;);" %>'`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting your binding expression tags (<%# ... %>) rendered in the markup, it means your LinkButton is not initialized in a binding container. A binding container can be, as @lincolnk demonstrated, an Repeater or GridView item, a Calendar cell, etc. Also, you do not have to prefix your function call with "javascript:". The value of the OnClientClick property is rendered as the handler of the anchor's **onclick** event.

Answer (score 2):

Looked everywhere on the net. Everyone says use CodeBehind. 
See my solution, which works even when my datavalue has a single quote in it like O'Neal.
**This will not work if your data item contains doublequotes**. But works for what I needed it to do which was pass in a person's name.
Note the backslashes inside the alert call.

```
OnClientClick="<%#string.Format(&quot;alert(\&quot;{0}\&quot;); return false; &quot;, Eval(&quot;NAME&quot;))%>"**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like
  OnClick='<%# "msgDisp(" + Eval("LocationId") + ");" %>'

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank lincolnk for his answer. I'm currently helping to build a new social network for googam.com. I have been searching for a few days for a solution to view a user's profile, in a datalist, in a jquery modal dialog popup. Setting the linkbutton OnClientClick in the ItemDataBound event solved the problem of passing the user id to the JQuery function to open a acsx user control in the popup window.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var mydiv = jQuery("#mydialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: '500',
            height: '400'
        }).css("font-size", "0.8em");
    });

    function ShowPopup(uid) {
        var mydiv = jQuery("#mydialog")
        //alert(uid)
        // Load the content using AJAX
        mydiv.load('Profile.aspx?id=' + uid);
        // Open the dialog        
        mydiv.dialog('open');
    }
```

//////////////

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataListItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim imageControl = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("Image1"), Image)
        Dim Uid As String = imageControl.ImageUrl

        Dim ProfileBtn As LinkButton = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("ProfileButton"), LinkButton)
        ProfileBtn.OnClientClick = String.Format("ShowPopup('{0}');return false;", Uid)

    End If
End Sub
```